Intermittent 500 Error in Digital Garden Test Environment
I am using the Digital Garden test environment provided by the Banno Digital Toolkit. Most of the time, the login functionality works fine. However, occasionally, I encounter a 500 Internal Server Error when trying to log in.
In the past, this issue would only last for a few minutes before resolving itself. Today, the error has persisted for several hours, and I cannot log in.
This leads me to believe that the issue might be on Garden's side. Could someone confirm if this is a known issue or if there’s anything I should check further from my side?
Thank you in advance for your help!

There was an incident earlier this morning in the Garden environment - everything should be back to normal now.

Thanks Sam. Do you have more details on what caused the incident? Is there a way to monitor or implement a health check for the Garden environment to catch such issues early?

There is http://status.banno.com - however, this is a platform-wide status for Banno and not necessarily specific to Garden.

So it's unclear why Garden occasionally has issues and prevents login

We don't generally provide public commentary about Garden - it is a test environment with no SLA in place. For planned maintenance and long-standing issues there will usually be a notice published here: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/notices/

The root cause is most likely on the server side. The fact that it works most of the time and occasionally throws a 500 error on login attempts is a clear indicator that it's not a problem on your side.
